# itertools.count function reading from py documents

Tags: python

Was trying to learn itertools from the python docs. I was going through `count` function and replicated 
the example given. However, I did not get any output to view.

```
def count(start=0, step=1):
    n = start
    while True:
        yield n
        n += step
```

output was :

```
>>> print(count(2.5,0.5))
<generator object count at 0x00000254BF3FEA48>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) (indicated by the `yield` keyword). It returns an (infinite) [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#functional-howto-iterators) over the yielded objects:

```
def count(start=0, step=1):
    n = start
    while True:
        yield n
        n += step
```

If you want to see proper output, you would have to iterate/consume it:

```
cnt = count(2.5, 0.5)
for i in range(10):
    x = next(cnt)
    print(x)
```

You can also just do:

```
for x in count(2.5, 0.5):
    print(x)
```

But that will go on forever ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you yield a value in a function, you create a generator.
So when you print your `count` function, something like this should be displayed:

```
<generator object count at 0x0000025614C3F248>
```

So in order to print the generated values, you have to iterate over the generator.

```
for e in count(2.5,0.5):
    print(e)
```

Or get the next value from it with `next()`

```
print(next(count(2.5,0.5)))
```